# Download image from url with google spreadsheet script

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm using google spreadsheet app to parse information from a webstore. So far I've managed to get all the needed information except the images of products. I have the link to the image stored in a variable like this:

```
var test = 'http://.....image.jpg'
```

what I need to do is to download the image to my PC into any folder without any confirmation, since all of this will be done in a loop to download all the images from a webpage.

Comment: Scripts on Google Spreadsheets cannot download files to your PC. However, they can get files and upload them to your Google Drive. Would you like that? If you really need to download files to your PC, then consider [using the Command line](https://superuser.com/questions/25538/how-to-download-files-from-command-line-in-windows-like-wget-or-curl).

Comment: Yes, I would like to try with google drive.